# f.label is not working in rails production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, label, production

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (5 for 3)):
14:       <div class="form-inline loginsubmit">
15:         <%= f.submit "Sign in" ,:class =>"actionbtn login-load"%>
16:         <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
17:         <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> 
18:         <%= f.label :remember_me %>
19:         <% end %>
20:       </div>
21:
app/views/users/sessions/new.html.erb:18:in `block in_app_views_users_sessions_new_html_erb__321696909397072435_46750480'
app/views/users/sessions/new.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_users_sessions_new_html_erb__321696909397072435_46750480'
```

I am using standard form of devise, at line no 9 there is form

```
<%=form_for(resource, :as=>resource_name,:url =>session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

It is working local both in development and production environment but on server it is not working in even development environment.
It is throwing same error for all f.label even I am passing more than 1 arguement
like

```
<%= f.label :remember_me, "Remember me", :class => "some_class" %>
```

For

```
<%= f.label>
```

the error is right that wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

When I changed f.label into label_tag or html  tag then it is working fine

Serverinfo:

```
aws
rails 3.2.11(3.2.13 also tried)
ruby 1.9.3
apache webserver
phusion passenger
mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope It will help. I just don't use erb. I use slim. But I think you will understand

```
h1 User login

= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :email, "Email"
    = f.email_field :email
  .field
    = f.label :password, "Password"
    = f.password_field :password
  .field
    = show_simple_captcha
  .field
    - if devise_mapping.rememberable?
      = f.label :remember_me do
        = f.check_box :remember_me
        '
        ' Remember me
  .actions
    = f.submit "Submit", :class => :btn

= render "users/shared/links"
```

I use nested checkbox in label. Result (checkbox part):

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="user_remember_me">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="user[remember_me]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[remember_me]" id="user_remember_me"> Remember me 
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: this issue is coming in every place where f.label is coming, so checkbox would not be an issue.           ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (5 for 3)):
    16:  </div>
    17: 
    18: <div class="control-group">
    19:   <%=f.label :name ,"Folder Name*", :class => "control-label"%>
    20:   <div class = "controls">
    21:     <%= f.text_field :name%>
    22:     <div class = "attachErrors hide">can't be blank</div>

Comment: Perhaps, your hosting has wrong version of rails. I have not  more ideas, sorry